How to use vaspkit to generate AIMD input files?
Is it possible to generate necessary AIMD input files using VASPKit?
Thanks

yes https://vaspkit.com/tutorials.html#generate-incar

@PranavkumarActually I just edited my question body. I forgot to mention AIMD. Regarding the AIMD is it possible?
